# HighCharts performance issue and alternative

Tags: jquery, charts, highcharts

Is there an alternative solution to HighCharts with better performance when we have really big data?

For example:

Try to use:

http://www.highcharts.com/studies/performance.php?seriesType=line+-+no+markers&chartCount=1&seriesPerChart=2&pointsPerSeries=4000&chartWidth=500&libSource=%2Fhighcharts.src.js

And test adding 3 or more series with 4000 and more points. There are a lot of performance issues. Is there a solution? Can I somehow overcome this problem or should I use an alternative solution for charts?

I need to display charts for about 33 series with 10.000 and more points per series.

Thanks

Comment: You should really think about downsampling your data.  33 series with 10,000 datapoints each will end up being a "blob" of color...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried [Highstock](http://www.highcharts.com/products/highstock) instead?
Demo with large data:
[52,000 points with data grouping](http://www.highcharts.com/stock/demo/data-grouping)
[1.7 million points with async loading](http://www.highcharts.com/stock/demo/lazy-loading)

Seriously 33 series simultaneously with 10K points?!?! That too in javascript? Why don't you give flash or silverlight a try? I have used [Telerik](http://demos.telerik.com/silverlight/), It has a nice charting suite for silverlight and is good on performance too

Comment: telerik can run on safari iPad?